# Her beauty is unmatched of all her friends

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. Her beauty is unmatched of all her friends.

Is that correct or .

> 2. Her beauty is **the** unmatched of all her friends.

Which one is correct.???

Comment: definite articles should not be used for generic concepts

Comment: Both seem wrong to me.

Comment: "unmatched by any of her friends" would be idiomatic.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct. Whether they mean what you want to say is a different question.

Comment: Clare I don't understand your comment. "Is unmatched of" may or may not be grammatical, but it is certainly not standard modern usage. "Is the unmatched of" places "the" in the middle of a verb, which is not grammatical. What do you think the meaning of that sentence is?

Comment: In a context where "the unmatched" is an established reference, such that we can treat the phrase as a pronoun, Clare's comment makes sense.  My problem is with the preposition.  In my dialect, "of" makes no sense here.  "By" seems plausible.  "Among" seems natural.  "Of" is simply confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Neither sentence given in the question is standard usage.

"Her beauty is unmatched by all her friends'" will certainly be accepted and understood.

Style is admittedly personal? I find "Her beauty is unmatched by all her friends'" awkward because the possessive at the end does not explicitly identify what is possessed. I'd prefer, purely as a matter of style,

"Her beauty is unmatched by that of her friends" or more succinctly

"Her friends' beauty does not match hers."